# I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException when i executed the runner clasas in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm

I have created a feature file and then created the selenium base class where i have created a method to read the data from configuration file and then i have given driver details in stepdefiniation class . Then created runner class and executed it .Getting the Null pointer exception in selenium base class . Can you please hep me out on this

```
//Selenium Base class
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SeleniumBaseclass
{

    Properties prop;
 public void Property()
    {

        try
        {
            File f= new File("C:\\Users\\watareuman9\\workspace\\Cucumberproject\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\config.property");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
             prop=new Properties();

                    prop.load(fis);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }



        public String getChromepath()
        {
            return prop.getProperty("ChromePath");
        }

        public String getAppurl()
        {
            return prop.getProperty("URL");
        }

    }


//stepdefination file:

    package Stepdfinations;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

    public class Accountstepdefinations  {

        @Given("^I navigated to the Login page$")
        public void i_navigated_to_the_Login_page() 
        {
            SeleniumBaseclass b1=new SeleniumBaseclass();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", b1.getChromepath());
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(b1.getAppurl());

        }

        //@When("^I click on the New Account link$")
        //public void i_click_on_the_New_Account_link() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           // throw new PendingException();


        //@Then("^I should see the New Account registration page$")
        //public void i_should_see_the_New_Account_registration_page() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //    throw new PendingException();
        }

    //
    //}

//Runner clasas:

package Stepdfinations;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features")



public class Runner 
{


}



//Error appearing as null exception in the following method:

public String getChromepath()
        {
            return prop.getProperty("ChromePath");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `SeleniumBaseclass.getChromepath()` before invoking `SeleniumBaseclass.property()`.

so, value of `prop` is `null` when you invoke `SeleniumBaseclass.getChromepath()`. So, NullpointerException is occurred.

Comment: so should i invoke the SeleniumBaseclass.property() in stepdefination class ?can you please elaborate it

Comment: You should instantiate `prop` in any way. but best way is as you told , you should invoke the SeleniumBaseclass.property() in stepdefination class